# How to save Excel to Azure blob storage with openpyxl in databricks

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, openpyxl, azure-databricks

I'm trying to load an Excel report template in Azure Blob Storage via Python's library openpyxl in Databricks,
edit this template and save to a new Excel file to another path in Azure Blob Storage.
However, I found that error "Operation not supported".

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side, PatternFill, Font, Alignment
from openpyxl.styles import numbers
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ENV = dbutils.widgets.get("ENV")
path = '/dbfs/mnt/EXCEL/TEMP/'
export = '/dbfs/mnt//EXCEL/EXPORT/'
file = 'Template.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path + file)
sheets = wb.sheetnames
ws = wb[sheets[0]]
old_max_row = ws.max_row
cell =ws.cell(row=old_max_row+1, column=1)
cell.value = -1401230.12

exp_path = export+'Test.xlsx'
wb.save(exp_path)
```

Error meassage:

```
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. However, I must edit cell such as fill color in cell, edit number format in cell and add some picture in my excel. So, I'm not sure that pandas will work for this issue.

Comment: The problem not with the pandas - problem is that DBFS doesn’t support random write operations that are necessary for writing Excel

Comment: Thanks so much Alex. You're right. It can solve my problem by saving file directly and move file to path as per your solution.